# Fix space issue on date picker material ui version 5

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datepicker

I'm using material ui version 5 mobile date picker. But when I select a value, it shows with spacing like below image.

[image: Mobile Date Picker]

But i need to remove spaces from this year, month and date. I'm using below date picker.

[Mobile Date Picker](https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/mobile-date-picker/)

How can I solve this?

My datepicker code is like below.

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
  <MobileDatePicker
    format={inputFormat}
    value={new Date(parseISO(value))}
    label={label}
    onChange={onChangeValue}
    views={views}
    className={classes.root}
    slotProps={{
      textField: {
        InputProps: {
          endAdornment: (
            <InputAdornment position="end">
              <EventIcon />
            </InputAdornment>
          ),
        },
        variant: inSideLabel
          ? VariantTypes.OUTLINED
          : VariantTypes.STANDARD,
        helperText: touched ? (errors as string) : undefined,
        error: touched && Boolean(errors),
      },
    }}
    sx={sx}
  />
</LocalizationProvider>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you mean the spacing between the numbers and the `/`?

Comment: @RubenSmn Yes correct

Comment: Can you update your question and add your code? [The examples on the docs](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-picker/#available-components) do not have this behavior.

Comment: @RubenSmn yes that is the case. there is not spaces in the document. but when i added the date picker it shows like above image with spaces.

Comment: This likely has to do with styling, but the code for the styling is missing `sx` and `classes.root`